# Swift AnyObject - Down casting an array of protocols to [AnyObject]

Tags: swift, protocols, anyobject

How do you downcast an array of protocol instances into `AnyObject`s? I've tried some of the more reasonable ideas in the code example below.

```
protocol Nameable : class {
    var name: String { get }
}

class Person: Nameable {
    var name: String

    init(name: String)
    {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Example {

    func setArray(array: [AnyObject]?, forKey: String)
    {
        print("hello world")
    }
}

var personOne = Person(name: "Evan")
var personTwo = Person(name: "Brian")

var array: [ Nameable ] = [ personOne, personTwo ]

var anotherArray = array.map({ $0 as AnyObject })    // OMG gross!
var yetAnotherArray = array as [ AnyObject ]         // Nope.
var evenYetAnotherArray = array as? [ AnyObject ]    // Nope.
var omgThisIsAnArray = Array<AnyObject>(array)       // Ha ha, srsly. Nope.

var myExample = Example()
myExample.setArray(anotherArray, forKey: "Named")
```

For what it's worth, `setArray(_ anArray: [AnyObject]?, forKey aKey: String)` method signature comes from Apple's `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` class, so I can't really redesign that to be type safe.

Comment: If an object conforms to `AnyObject` but its type is more distinct it's not necessary to cast the object to `AnyObject` to match a method signature. In your case – as Eric mentions in his answer – the issue is that `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` supports only property list compliant types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's less than perfect, but it works if the protocol and class are both `@objc` (and the class subclasses `NSObject`):

```
@objc protocol Nameable: class {
    var name: String { get }
}

@objc class Person: NSObject, Nameable {
    var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

...

```
var array: [Nameable] = [personOne, personTwo]
let array2 = array as [AnyObject] // ✓
```

Comment: Thank you! The key here is that `AnyObject` is annotated with `@objc`, whereas my protocol is _not_. Therefore it makes sense that it's not possible to cast.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer your question directly, but I don't think this will work like you expect.

From the docs for NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore setArray:

> An array whose contents can be stored in a property list format. In other words, the objects in the array must be of the types **NSNumber**, **NSString**, **NSDate**, **NSData**, **NSArray**, or **NSDictionary**. The total size (in bytes) of the array and its contents must not exceed the per-key size limits.

You're trying to put data in that is not any of the above and I'm guessing you'll run into issues.

Something like this would work:

```
import UIKit // For String<->NSString bridging

protocol Nameable : class  {
    var name: String { get }
}

class Person: Nameable {
    var name: String

    init(name: String)
    {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Example {

    func setArray(array: [AnyObject]?, forKey: String)
    {
        print("hello world")
    }
}

var personOne = Person(name: "Evan")
var personTwo = Person(name: "Brian")

var array: [ Nameable ] = [ personOne, personTwo ]

var nameArray = array.map({ $0.name }) // Now [String]

var myExample = Example()
myExample.setArray(nameArray, forKey: "Named")
```

Or you could serialize your Swift objects some other way to get them into one of the supported classes.